# Bing GeoCode Search API to find local business in Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am using the Bing Search API (http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/searchservice/searchservice.svc?wsdl) in my WP7 app to find local business in India but I am not getting any result as part of the response. But when I search for business in US, it gives me proper results. Can anyone tell me whether the Search service works only for US and not for India or any other countries?
If it does not support, can you advice what could be the other alternatives to fetch local business (e.g. restaurants near Hyderabad, India) data in WP7 app?
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Saikat

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the Bing Search API is moving to the Azure Marketplace, so you need to look into the following :-

http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/05/17/bing-developer-update-2.aspx

I am currently in the process of migrating my applications over to using Azure therefore I am aware of a section in the migration guide relating to the Market your search results relate to therefore you might be able to make your search specific to India. There is an online tool that you can use to determine the search URL to use and the results this brings back so you should be able to determine quickly whether a Bing Search via the Azure Marketplace returns the results you require.